# Querying double has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a double has_many :through relation like this:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :surveyquestions
  has_many :questions, through: :surveyquestions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :surveyquestions
  has_many :surveys, through: :surveyquestions
  has_many :kpiquestions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :kpis, through: :kpiquestions
end

class Kpi < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kpiquestions
  has_many :questions, through: :kpiquestions
end
```

Now I want to query for questions which have a specific `survey_id` and a specific `kpi_id`, but I am unsure how to query this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey you can try this way**

```
 Question.includes(:surveys,:kpis).where(:surveys => {:survey_id => 1}, :kpis => {:kpi_id => 2})
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be the correct query: `Question.includes(:surveys,:kpis).where(:surveys => {:id => 1}, :kpis => {:id => 1})`